# Why I am getting 'no-unused-expressions' error while trying to display each object value in the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display Todo titles using map function within the Todos component. However I am getting error saying:

Line 6:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Todos.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Todos extends Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.todos.map(todo => {
        <h3>{todo.title}</h3>
    });
    };
};

export default Todos;
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Todos from './components/Todos';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    todos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Take out the trash',
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Dinner with wife',
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Meeting with boss',
        completed: false
      },
    ]
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Todos todos={this.state.todos} />   
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Your `.map` isn't returning anything. That JSX inside it is going unused.

Answer (score 1):

A return is missing:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Todos extends Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.todos.map(todo => {
        return (
          <h3>{todo.title}</h3>
        );
    });
  }
}

export default Todos;
```